# how to decrypt aes-256-gcm in PHP using IV & TAG

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I've found a difficult way to decrypt a string using aes-256-gcm, iv, and TAG.
Here are the parameters that I get.

```
$password = 'code1234';
$data = 'f4oGPQaf9ZolRc9oh8VLRiJWK2B35tkHq9L6WvrE+jbjS1mfi0fJB7re+0kVM2RRLiAEPBSFtIQzlJ5055yRlntIZwwpRvAN1cUBS0ze3hb+FrcO43vtBuuqftDw0exfmorPM5SOaKj3KtEQjB2ypwtbnQNCtegNizs6niqAdvs/XztlZPbq08Y=';

$ivstring = 'D7GVFFLn+K0sNj+YRskGTw==';
$tagstring = '9GSCia0QDujWTn3zpIRbCw==';
```

I use this function to decrypt

```
openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes-256-gcm', $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivstring, $tagstring);
```

but it always returns with the following error

> Setting tag for AEAD cipher decryption failed

how to decrypt aes-256-gcm in PHP using IV & TAG

UPDATE :
the encryption are come from main app using node js. I tried to decrypt within nodejs app, it's working normally. I tried to convert decrypt function to PHP, but always get errors. Here the encrypt and decrypt script function

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

// Demo implementation of using `aes-256-gcm` with node.js's `crypto` lib.
const aes256gcm = (key) => {
    const ALGO = 'aes-256-gcm';
    const aes_password = key || 'code1234';
    const aes_key = crypto.createHash('md5').update(aes_password, 'utf-8').digest('hex').toUpperCase();

    // encrypt returns base64-encoded ciphertext
    const encrypt = (str) => {

        const iv = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16), 'utf8');
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGO, aes_key, iv);

        let enc = cipher.update(str, 'utf8', 'base64');
        enc += cipher.final('base64');

        const ivString = iv.toString('base64');
        const authTagString = cipher.getAuthTag().toString('base64')
        return [enc, ivString, authTagString];
    };

    // decrypt decodes base64-encoded ciphertext into a utf8-encoded string
    const decrypt = (enc, ivString, authTagString) => {
        const iv = new Buffer(ivString, 'base64');
        const authTag = new Buffer(authTagString, 'base64');
//console.log(iv);
  //      console.log(authTag);
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, aes_key, iv);
   //     console.log(iv);
        decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
        let str = decipher.update(enc, 'base64', 'utf8');
        console.log(str);
        str += decipher.final('utf8');
        return str;
    };

    return {
        encrypt,
        decrypt,
    };
};

module.exports = aes256gcm;
```

Comment: @kelalaka the encryption are from main app with nodejs script. I will add encrypt and decrypt function on my question.

Comment: How you transfer the key?

Comment: Why are you setting `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` when you aren't providing raw data?  You might find the PHP example in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) useful.

Comment: @kelalaka what key ?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I don't know, I just found some tutorial how to decrypt aes-256-gcm, it's using `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA `

Comment: You need to use `base64_decode()`. I'd recommend looking into migrating away from OpenSSL and towards libsodium instead.